# Azure SQL - block all traffic from outside the USA

Tags: azure

How can I block all outside US traffic to my Azure SQL?  I've used Front Door WAP with my App Services. How do you do this with an Azure SQL instance ?  I have already set Firewall rules.

thx in advance

Comment: This may be better answered on ServerFault as I suspect it will involve disallowing public access and setting up a private VNet with your App Service and whatever DevOps service you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to only allow a few IP's to communicate directly with the SQL server and "allow-list" those few IP addresses via **IP Firewall Rules**.  This is also the most secure method.  It is recommended if you have a VM in Azure connecting to the DB, you assign that VM a static IP address.

If that is not possible, you can enable **Private Link**.  Private Link allows you to connect to a server via a private endpoint. A private endpoint is a private IP address within a specific virtual network (VNet) and Subnet.

Once Azure SQL is connected to a VNet, You can filter network traffic between subnets using either or both of the following options:

- **Network security groups:** Network security groups and application
  security groups can contain multiple inbound and outbound security
  rules that enable you to filter traffic to and from resources by
  source and destination IP address, port, and protocol. To learn more,
  see Network security groups or Application security groups.
- **Network virtual appliances:** A network virtual appliance is a VM that performs
  a network function, such as a firewall, WAN optimization, or other
  network function. To view a list of available network virtual
  appliances that you can deploy in a virtual network, see Azure
  Marketplace.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview#filter-network-traffic